# mysql update row with info from previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

After searching for quite some time, none of the answers I found were really helpfull.
I have a table with values, now i would like to update the table like so:

```
set Rowx, Col3 to Rowx-1, Col2
```

I have been trying to do something like that with SQL Fiddle but I just cant figure it out. I also read somewhere that it is totally impossible as it is not supported by MYSQL, I find this hard to believe.

Here is my SQL Fiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/565c37/1/0

EDIT: The code was actually correct, just swapped the + and - and that made me blind.

Final Query:

```
UPDATE 
    tableX AS upd
  JOIN
    tableX AS simple
      ON  simple.Col1 = upd.Col1 -1
SET
    upd.Col2 = simple.Col3 ;
```

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle link seems to do the update you're looking for?  What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `- 1` rather than `+ 1`:

```
UPDATE tableX upd JOIN
       tableX simple
       ON simple.Col1 = upd.Col1 - 1
    SET upd.Col3 = simple.Col2 ;
```

If you are going to have sequential ids, you should use numbers to represent them, rather than strings.  I don't think the `join` can make use of indexes because of the type conversion.

Comment: The rows will be somewhat sequential, but they have a week nr. and a year. So they are not unique. Thanks for the answer, I think I need a rubber duck on my desk.